# How to filter the first table before using the left join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have this code:

```sql
SELECT 
    c.ChapterNo, l.LessonNo 
FROM 
    Chapter c LEFT JOIN Lesson l ON c.ChapterNo = l.ChapterNo
```

which returns all the rows in chapter table even without similar value in lesson table.

what i want to do is to filter the chapter table by the description 'geometry' before using `left join`. I used the `where`-clause after the code like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    c.ChapterNo, l.LessonNo 
FROM 
    Chapter c LEFT JOIN Lesson l ON c.ChapterNo = l.ChapterNo 
WHERE 
    c.desc = 'geometry'
```

but it does not return anything.

In addition, I am writing the SQL code connected to my program in VB.NET.

Comment: Please tag with your DBMS, and also provide sample data, along with the expected results of the query.

Comment: The code is correct. If you use Oracle - use `UPPER(c.desc) = 'GEOMETRY'`

Comment: What is your sample input and desired output?

Comment: my database has two tables named Chapter and Lesson. The Chapter Table has ChapterNo as its primary key and Desc (probably geometry or trigo). However, the Lesson table has LessonNo as its primary key and ChapterNo as its foreign key. I want to return the values from the chapter table with desc=geometry ONLY.

Comment: Please, don't be deaf to our comments. You got to post **what** db engine you're using

Comment: sql server. i am sorry i have slow internet connection that's why  am too slow answering your questions @T.S.

Comment: @Teja for example, i input many chapters in my chapter table with geometry or trigo as description, i want the result/output to be filtered by those chapters with geometry as description only.

Comment: @ABCDE Show sample data please.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Sql Server, as you've posted, you shouldn't not have issues with case sensitivity. Your query is correct and you must simply don't have chapters where `c.desc = 'geometry'`

You also asked how to filter query **before join**. You can do it by using inline query

```sql
SELECT 
    c.ChapterNo, l.LessonNo 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM Chapter WHERE c.desc = 'geometry') c 
    LEFT JOIN Lesson l ON c.ChapterNo = l.ChapterNo
```

This way you really filtering chapters before join. However, it is up to DBMS optimizer how it executes it. May be just same way as original query - gotta see explain plan for that

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one.

```
SELECT 
    c.ChapterNo, l.LessonNo 
FROM 
    Chapter c 
LEFT JOIN Lesson l ON c.ChapterNo = l.ChapterNo AND c.desc = 'geometry'
```

This will match 'geometry' and remaining will be NULL

Comment: already tried sir. but did not work. i think it is not really possible to filter the first table using the left join. but dont worry sir, i already found an alternative solution for my problem. thanks a lot!

Comment: _" i already found an alternative solution"_ - you started filtering `lessons` with `desc="geometry"`?

Comment: This is no different from his original design